# Debug dockercompose Visual Studio ASP.NET Core 2.2 over HTTPS getting error

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm struggling with running Docker compose ASP.NET Core 2.2. I'm setting the following:

**DockerFile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
...
```

**docker-compose-override.yml**

```
  identity-api:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - Logging__LogLevel__Default=Warning
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=123
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    ports:
      - "5015:80"
      - "6015:443"
    networks:
      - default
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
```

I've already generated a certificate and configured the local machine from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-compose-https?view=aspnetcore-2.2#windows-using-linux-containers) like below:

[image]

Output certificate like below:

[image]

But when I press <kbd>F5</kbd> to debug `docker-compose`, I get the following error

> Interop.Crypto.OpenSslCryptographicException: 'error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file'

[image]

**Note**: I'm running Windows desktop using the WSL 2 based engine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops, the problem is caused by **docker-compose-override.yml**

```
volumes:
  - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
```

You should point out exactly the *host path*, or do something with 2 steps like this:

- Step 1. Copy the `aspnetapp.pfx` into your root project (**The same level** with `dockercompose.override.yml`) files.

```
https/aspnetapp.pfx
```

- Step 2. Change the *host path* in **docker-compose-override.yml** to

```
volumes:
  - ./https/aspnetapp.pfx:/https/aspnetapp.pfx:ro
```